# Only write data to text file if the line doesnt match any others

Tags: c#

I want to add data into a text file based on a specific output. It will read an XML file and write a certain line to a text file. If the data is already written into the text file, I don't want to write it again.

### Code

```
public void output(string folder)
{
    string S = "Data" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".xml";
    //Trades.Save(S);
    string path = Path.Combine(folder, S);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    XDocument f = new XDocument(Trades);

    f.Save(path);

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
        @"H:\Test" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd") + ".txt", true))
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("CertainData"))
            {
                file.WriteLine(line);
                if (File.ReadAllLines(path).Any(x => x.Equals(line)))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] tradeRefLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                    File.WriteAllLines(path, tradeRefLines); ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it will still write the line even if the data is exactly the same elsewhere. I don't want duplicate lines.

Any advice?

### Edit

The `CertainData` is a reference number.

I have a bunch of files that have data in them and the piece I want to seperate and put into a text file is `CertainData` field, which will have a reference number.

Sometimes the files I get sent will have the same formatted information inside it with the `CertainData` appearing in them for reference.

When i run this programme, if the text file i have already contains the "CertainData" reference number inside it, i dont want it to be written

If you need anymore clarification let me know and i will update the post

Answer (score 0):

EDITED :

```
public void output(string folder)
{
    string S = "Data" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".xml";
    //Trades.Save(S);
    string path = Path.Combine(folder, S);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    XDocument f = new XDocument(Trades);

    f.Save(path);

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);

    bool isExist = false;
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"H:\Test" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd") + ".txt", true))
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("CertainData"))
            {
                isExist = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isExist)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(path, "CertainData" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think i explained myself properly, I want to right the "CertainData" part but i dont want the "CertainData" part to be written in if it matches up with a line in the .txt file

for Example, if i have:
23
854
454
4
and i read an XML which has "854" in the "CertainData" field, i dont want to write it in because "854" is already wirtten there

Comment: so @Nonagon you are saying that in textfile there are data in line1 is 10 20 30 line2 is 40 50 60 and line3 is 70 80 90, now, by reading XML you get 50 in "CertainData" field, so 50 is in line2 so no need to write in line2, am i right ?

Comment: Kind of but imagine 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 & 90 all all on there own line so 10 is line 1 20 is line 2 etc
now after readint the xml file, finding the certain data field which is say 20, it will look at the text file and say "oh. 20 is already in the file, no need to write it in"  hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

Try with this LINQ:

```
var previousLines = new HashSet<string>();
File.WriteAllLines(destPath, File.ReadLines(sourcePath)
                              .Where(line => previousLines.Add(line)));
```